# Editing output in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-formatting

I have the following code:

```
nodeCount = 10
vertexCount = 15

vertices = {}
while len(vertices) < vertexCount:
    x = random.randint (1, nodeCount)
    y = random.randint (1, nodeCount)
    if x == y: continue
    if y < x: x, y = y, x
    w = random.randint(0,10)
    vertices [x, y] = w

print (nodeCount, vertexCount)
for (x, y), w in vertices.items ():
    print (x, y, w)
```

When I run this I am getting something similar to the following as output:

```
(10, 15)
(3, 8, 10)
(6, 8, 1)
(4, 10, 7) #there's more output but not necessary to post
```

I'm trying to get the format of my output to be the following however where there are not parenthesis or commas are displayed in the output, so that I may then pipe that output to something else I'm working on:

```
10 15
3 8 10
6 8 1
4 10 7
```

I've read up about using .split() however I don't generally use Python and am running into issues trying to change the way my output is formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2, `print` is a statement, not a method, so call it without the parenthesis:

```
print nodeCount, vertexCount
...
print x, y, w
```

If you do call it with parenthesis, you would be creating a `tuple` instead. And when `print` prints a tuple, it wrap the content inside parenthesis because that's the `tuple` representation.

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary There you go, I always forgot the exact term, sometimes I even said _reserved word_ :) Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that, very simple fix :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.x, `print` is *not* a function (it's a *statement*), so what you are doing in the line:

```
print (x, y, w)
```

is that you are packing `x, y and w` in a `tuple`, and printing it. Therefore, the output will be a `tuple`.

**What can you do?**

Just remove the parenthesis `()`:

```
print x, y, w
```